# How to make an MS-DOS style console program?

Tags: pi-4, gui, serial-console

I want to make a console input/output program on Raspberry Pi. I'm just learning C programming by making some simple guessing games and calculator applications. I want to make an interface that's more than the terminal constantly printing the same messages.

I have seen some sample code for MS-DOS style compilers that uses the conio.h library. Is there a similar alternative for

Comment: Aka. [a *terminal user interface* (TUI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the curses library.  From your description it will probably do what you want.

Google for "curses library c tutorial".